# Limit number of data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I connected my datatables with websocket to display live data from backend. The data is live feed so the row is added continuously.

**Question:** How do I make datatables to remove the old data when it reaches for example 1000 rows, so in one table only 1000 rows are displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may listen for `preDraw` event which is fired exactly before you redraw datatable as you pushed new data in. So, you may check whether the row count is exceeded and find and remove oldest entry.

That might work, I guess:

```js
//define initial data sample
const srcData = [{parameter: 'CPU usage, %', value: Math.floor(Math.random()*100), timestamp: (new Date()).toString()}];
//define datatable object
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'parameter', data: 'parameter'},
    {title: 'value', data: 'value'},
    {title: 'timestamp', data: 'timestamp'}
  ]
});
//emulate new data insertion
const dataPooler = window.setInterval(function(){
 dataTable.row.add({parameter: 'CPU usage, %', value: Math.floor(Math.random()*100), timestamp: (new Date()).toString()}).draw();
},3000);
//listen for new draws, purge oldest entry
dataTable.on('preDraw', function(){
 if(dataTable.rows().count() < 5) return;
  //grab the oldest entry timestamp
 let oldestTimestamp = dataTable.column(2).data().toArray().map(entry => new Date(entry)).sort()[0].toString();
 //look through the table and purge corresponding entry if table has more than 10 entries
 let oldestEntryIndex = dataTable.column(2).data().indexOf(oldestTimestamp)
 dataTable.row(oldestEntryIndex).remove();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="mytable"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah I thought there is an easy way maybe an option in the API to make this happens. But this is simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: I think, there couldn't be default option, since purged row is user data specific - you need to get rid of the oldest entry, someone might wish to remove rows by the biggest/lowest value in certain column. And with that approach you got maximum flexibility at the cost of few lines of code.  So, if it solved your problem, you may accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you! but in one note. above code changes the original string representation of the datetime (the map to datetime), so if you use that to search the row index, you won't find it.